# Scala: Parse HTML-fragment

Tags: xml, scala, lift

Our database stores HTML *fragments* like f.ex. `<p>A.</p><p>B.</p>`. I want to include the Html fragements from the database into a Lift snippet.

To do that, I tried to use the `XML.loadString()`-method to convert the fragement into a `scala.xml.Elem`, but this only works for *full* valid XML-documents:

```
import scala.xml.XML
@Test
def doesnotWork() {
  val result = XML.loadString("<p>A</p><p>B</p>")
  assert(result === <p>A</p><p>B</p>)
}

@Test
def thisWorks() {
  val result = XML.loadString("<test><p>A</p><p>B</p></test>")
  assert(result === <test><p>A</p><p>B</p></test>)
}
```

The test `doesnotWork` results in an exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 10; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

Is it possible to convert just (valid) fragements to XML?

Comment: Unless your fragments are XHTML, you will want to parse with [Html5.parse](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.util.Html5$).

Comment: And by parsing your own HTML, you are avoiding [Lift's XSS protections](http://seventhings.liftweb.net/security). Be sure to sanitize your HTML before sending back to the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using Lift, you can wrap your XML in [`lift:children`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.builtin.snippet.Children$) as a workaround. The [`Children`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.builtin.snippet.Children$) snippet simply returns the element's children; and is very useful for wrapping fragments you need to parse.

```
@Test
def thisAlsoWorks() {
  val result = XML.loadString("<lift:children><p>A</p><p>B</p></lift:children>")
  assert(result === <lift:children><p>A</p><p>B</p></lift:children>)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the Children snippet.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a full valid XML document, but you do need a single top-level tag.

As you observed, the following works:

```
XML.loadString("<fragment><p>A</p><p>B</p></fragment>")
```

You could then either store a sequence of `Elem`s, or wrap them in a custom tag and extract the sequence using `.descendant`.

Comment: This also works - thank you. But I will use the simple Children-Snippet-workaround.